# Getting missing prefab error in unity

Tags: unity, linux, prefabs

[image]

Getting the following error while loading a project on unity. I'm usung ubuntu

Comment: To help you solve this problem, we'll need to know the specific series of steps you took that led to it. Without that, all we can tell you is the same thing Unity is saying: "something in your project is referencing a prefab with this specific ID, but no prefab with that ID was found in your assets folders". This can occur when you copy/move files into your project without their accompanying `.meta` files. How did these files come to be in your project? Also, be sure to share error messages as text for better search indexing and accessibility, to get more eyes on your question.

Comment: @DMGregory I have cloned this project into my local https://github.com/fabio914/EyeTrackingKeyboard and I got that error

Comment: Make sure those steps are described in your question, and that you show the error message in text form, not as an image.